# Preprocessing field with two distributions

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I'm doing multiclass classification on tabular data.

One of the fields of the table is a monetary amount value. I see two problems:

- The first is that there are positive and negative values up to very large numbers in both positive and negative directions. This prevents me from taking the log (negative values). Also shifting so that all values are positive and then taking the log is probably not a good option as it would give a very big variation on the negative numbers and a comparatively small on the big ones because of the characteristics of the log function.
- The second problem is that positive and negative values are distributed differently. If I take a log on them individually (separating at zero and taking abs) they are normally distributed, but with significantly different means and stds. This to me implies that I should make two fields out of this one.

The question is how to do this. I could:

1. Put the two values in same field (after abs and log) and add a second field with a boolean designating positive or negative.
2. Make one field for positives values and one for negative values (also abs and log), so that always only one of the fields would contain a value and otherwise be zero or an extremely negative values.

Any suggestions on which path to take, completely new suggestions or corrections?

PS: I'm using a NN as a classifier because one of the fields is a variable length text field with rich variation, no fixed dictionary and high positional dependence between "words".

Comment: when you have this problem in one column try to split it to 2 columns where one column will show positive value (or $0$ if negative) and second negative value ($0$ otherwise)